# Find a sequence in $\ell^p$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that $\cup_{1\leq r < p}\ell^r \subset \ell^p$. The first part is easy, but I need to find a sequence $x\in\ell^p\backslash\cup_{1\leq r < p} \ell^r$  to prove that the inclusion is strict and I don't find anything. Could you please help me?

Many thanks.

Comment: What is $\ell^p$ in this context?

Comment: $\ell^p = \{ \{x_j\} : x_j\in \mathbb C \vee \mathbb R, \left(\sum_{j\geq 1} |x_j|^p\right)^{1/p} <\infty\}$

Comment: Thanks. I will try to find an example.

Comment: Thanks to you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x_n=\frac  1{n^{1/p}(\log\, n)^{2/p}}$ ($n \geq 2$) is an example.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot